# Disadvantage of customer sharing in PrestaShop 1.5

Tags: prestashop

I am thinking of modifying the authorization feature of Prestashop, wherein multiple shops can share customers even when shops are not within the same group. For example, when a customer logs in the default shop, after checking out his cart he can go to the next shop without the need to relogin again. More convenient for the customers, I think.

My question is, will that pose any security threat or any other disadvantage to my shops and to my customers? As of now I can't think of any, but I want to know the point of view of PS experts first before I dive into the codes.

And btw, if I am to start editing my shop, is there any method that I can use so that I dont need to edit the core codes?

Comment: Hi, use hooks instead of editing the core files. If it is the impossible that use the override (http://bel.vg/06)

Answer (score 0):

Use prestashop's override if you really need to change core

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors